# NextAuth - Redirect to the original requested page after successful login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

Can't get this to work. I have a NextJS application with NextAuth. On each page, I do a **getServerSideProps()** where I check if user is logged in / has session, redirect to the page they want. If no session - send to an unauthorized page.

Basically, if user requests **/page1** - and they're not authorized, it sends them to signin, trying to keep **/page1** in a querystring of some sort, so after successful login - I can redirect them to the page the originally requested.

So I have something like

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context : any){
    const session = await unstable_getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions)  
    if (!session) {
        //context.resolvedUrl = HAS THE REQUESTED PATH...
        return {
            redirect: {               
              destination: `/api/auth/signin?redirect=${context.resolvedUrl}`, 
              permanent: false,
            },
        }
    }else{ 
        return {
            props: {
              session,
            }
          }
    } 
}
```

I also see a callbacks API for NextAuth -> https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks - which has a "redirect" callback - but looks like it can only do url / baseUrl from params.

Can anyone lead me how to achieve this using NextAuth + NextJS.

Thank you.